Is deletion of no longer needed helper functions pythonic?
I saw a .py file like this:
def _initmodule():
    ...

def api_func1(): pass
def api_func2(): pass

_initmodule()
del _initmodule  # <--- pythonic?

The init function is run once and after that it is not needed any more and gets deleted.
Wondering if it is a pythonic/idiomatic I briefly scanned the std library and found a similiar pattern in the pickletools:
def assure_pickle_consistency(verbose=False):
    ...
assure_pickle_consistency()
del assure_pickle_consistency

and another one in urllib/parse.
def _fix_result_transcoding():
    ...
_fix_result_transcoding()
del _fix_result_transcoding

I have probably overlooked some occurrences, but definitiely, it is a rare pattern.
Is it something we should not forget to do?

This use of del is probably only useful to prevent people from importing the helper function directly, ignoring the conventional private name (a leading underscore already avoids import *). It is neither necessary nor terribly Pythonic, and I personally would never do so. That said, this question is opinion-based and therefore off-topic.
